# The method fun(String) is ambiguous for the type TestInterviewquestion class

Tags: java

This public class `TestInterviewquestion` has these methods and all parameters are unique. But I get the compile time error *"The method fun(String) is ambiguous for the type TestInterviewquestion class"*.
Can someone see the problem?

```
public static void fun(String s) {
    System.out.println("String");
}

public static void fun(Object o) { 
    System.out.println("Object");
}

public static void fun(Integer i) {
    System.out.println("Integer");
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    fun(null);
}
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: please clarify what you want to ask and could you post the error details also

Comment: This error is in compile time as ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is why `fun(null)` is ambiguous, the reason is that both `public static void fun(Integer i)` and `public static void fun(String s)` can accept a `null`, but since neither of String and Integer is more specific than the other, the compiler can't choose between the two.

Comment: even `public static void fun(Object o)` can also accept `null` parameters.

Comment: @Blip Yes, but since Object is less specific than both Integer and String, the compiler will prefer fun(Integer) and fun(String) over fun(Object).

Answer (score 4):

Compilation of this code gives ambiguous call because

```
fun(null)
```

is applicable to all the overloaded method since string,Integer and Object variables can hold null reference and java doesn't know which overloaded method to call .

Comment: yes, but in case we used only string and object then fun(null) method call directly string param, Not giving any ambiguous . so since neither of String and Integer is more specific than the other, the compiler can't choose between the two.